# How to get CONTEXT for the provider to work? Flutter

Tags: flutter, state, provider

In the Future fetchStudentInfo() function, i would like to use the userId from my Auth class to do filtering. The userId is embedded in the URL and it will retrieve data from database. But, the issue is that the context is lacking in the function itself. However, I couldn't figure out a way to pass in the context. It would be great if any legend could help me. The solution which retrieve data from internet is found on the flutter documentation. And i wouldn't like to hard code the userId.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../model/student.dart';
import '../provider/auth.dart';

Future<Student> fetchStudentInfo() async {
  final auth = Provider.of<Auth>(context);
  final response = await http.post(
      'https://intermediary-sharpe.000webhostapp.com/Student/read_one.php?userId=$auth.userId');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Student.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed');
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  Future<Student> student;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
    student = fetchStudentInfo();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<Student>(
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data.studentId);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
        future: student,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../model/http_exception.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  String userId;
  Timer _authTimer;

  bool get isAuthenticated {
    return token != null;
  }

  String get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url =
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:$urlSegment?key=AIzaSyCkNZysDY4PGpScw2jUlBpd0mvpGjgSEag';
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
      _token = responseData['idToken'];
      userId = responseData['localId'];
      _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
        Duration(
          seconds: int.parse(
            responseData['expiresIn'],
          ),
        ),
      );
      _autoLogout();
      notifyListeners();
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final userData = json.encode({
        'token': _token,
        'userId': userId,
        'expiryDate': _expiryDate.toIso8601String(),
      });
      prefs.setString('userData', userData);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  //Auto Login Function
  Future<bool> tryAutoLogin() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!prefs.containsKey('userData')) {
      return false;
    }
    final extractedUserData =
        json.decode(prefs.getString('userData')) as Map<String, Object>;
    final expiryDate = DateTime.parse(extractedUserData['expiryDate']);
    if (expiryDate.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
      return false;
    }
    _token = extractedUserData['token'];
    userId = extractedUserData['userId'];
    _expiryDate = expiryDate;
    notifyListeners();
    _autoLogout();
    return true;
  }

  //SignUp function
  Future<void> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signUp');
  }

  //Login Function
  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signInWithPassword');
  }

  //Logout Function
  Future<void> logout() async {
    _token = null;
    userId = null;
    _expiryDate = null;
    if (_authTimer != null) {
      _authTimer.cancel();
      _authTimer = null;
    }
    notifyListeners();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.clear();
  }

  //Auto Logout function
  void _autoLogout() {
    if (_authTimer != null) {
      _authTimer.cancel();
    }
    final timeToExpiry = _expiryDate.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds;
    _authTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: timeToExpiry), logout);
  }

  //PHP related functions

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@lyio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419001/lyio), you need to modify the function to pass the context, however after passing context, you cannot call it  from initState as stated in [documentation of initState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)

> `BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` from this method. However, `didChangeDependencies` will be called immediately following this method, and `BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` can be used there.

Getting provider with Provider.of(context) under the hood is using the inherited widget, so cannot be called using context from initState

So implement instead of initState use [didChangeDependencies](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html) to call your `fetchStudentsInfo(context)` method

Comment: OMG! This solved my issue! Thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the easiest solution be to pass the context into `fetchStudentInfo`?

You would change `fetchStudentInfo()` to `fetchStudentInfo(BuildContext context)`. And then, when you call the method you pass in the required context. That way, you have the appropriate context available.

Comment: After i modifeid the fetchStudentInfo() to fetchStudentInfo(BuildContext context), the function in the initState gt an error. However if i pass the context into the arguments, an error occured, Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';

Comment: Have a look at your imports. Maybe you are importing `BuildContext` from the wrong package?

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using the `fetchStudentInfo()` outside of the state class, then just move that method into the state class and the issue will be resolved.

Since Any state class has a `context` getter defined by default./

I just realized how improper this answer was.

**Update:**
According to the answer by @dlohani, `didChangeDependencies` should be used in stead of `initState`.

So what you can do is following:

1. Pass `BuildContext` as parameter in the `fetchStudentInfo` method
2. Override `didChangeDependencies` in state class & call `fetchStudentInfo`  from here instead of `initState`